# How to let TextFieldTableCell handle focus loss as commit instead of cancellation?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

The default behavior of a TextFieldTableCell in JavaFX is:

- Hit ENTER: commit the edit,
- Hit ESC: cancel the edit,
- Focus is lost: cancel the edit.

The cancellation of the edit when focus is lost is very unnatural, and causes my users to lose data.

I already tried to create an alternative implementation of TextFieldTableCell, where I added a listener on the `textfield.focusedProperty()` to force a commit, but this doesn't work well at all.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how this behavior can be improved?

My adapted `createTextField`-function:

```
private static <T> TextField createTextField(final Cell<T> cell, final StringConverter<T> converter) {
    final TextField textField = new TextField(getItemText(cell, converter));

    // Use onAction here rather than onKeyReleased (with check for Enter),
    // as otherwise we encounter RT-34685
    textField.setOnAction(event -> {
        if (converter == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Attempting to convert text input into Object, but provided "
                            + "StringConverter is null. Be sure to set a StringConverter "
                            + "in your cell factory.");
        }
        cell.commitEdit(converter.fromString(textField.getText()));
        event.consume();
    });
    textField.setOnKeyReleased(t -> {
        if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
            cell.cancelEdit();
            t.consume();
        }
    });

    textField.focusedProperty().addListener(observable -> {
        if (!textField.isFocused()) {
            cell.commitEdit(converter.fromString(textField.getText()));
        }
    });

    return textField;
}
```

Comment: i think you need to focus on your cell itself, and make it commit so as to render it as lable for your `TextField` but i am guessing you forcing commit is useless because its not in edit mode no more.. im not well versed in this part though..